# mongodb error no documents found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Here is my code to find winners of a contest :

```
var date   = moment().subtract('days', 1).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(date)
Contest.findOne({date: date}, function(err, contest){
    if(!err){
        if(contest){
            Participant.find({ questionID : contest._id, random : { $near : [Math.random(), 0] } }).limit(5).exec(function(err, participants){
                async.map(participants, function(participant, callback) {
                    contest.winners.push(participant)
                    contest.save(function(err) {
                        callback(err);
                    })
                }, function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Added winners to contest")
                    } else
                        console.log(err)
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("No contest found")
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Schema :

```
var ContestSchema = new Schema(
{
    question:{ 
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    answers:[{ 
        option: {type: String},
        correct: {type: Boolean, default : false}
    }],
    date: { 
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    priority: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        default : 0
    },
    winners : [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Participant' 
    }]
})

/*
 *Participant Schema
 */

var ParticipantSchema = new Schema(
{
    questionID:{ 
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    userID:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    name:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    email:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    mobile:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    address:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    landmark:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    city:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    state:{ 
        type: String, 
        trim: true
    },
    random:{
        type: [Number], 
        default : [Math.random(), 0],
        index: '2d'
    }
})

mongoose.model('Contest', ContestSchema)
mongoose.model('Participant', ParticipantSchema)
```

While saving winners to the contest, it saves the winners, but I am getting error :

```
{
    "status": {
        "error": 1,
        "message": {
            "message": "No matching document found.",
            "name": "VersionError"
        }
    }
}
```

What is this error and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try rewriting the async.map operation. This would result in a single call to contest.save and you don't have to fear any race conditions.

```
async.map(participants, function(participant, callback) {
    contest.winners.push(participant)
    callback();
}, function(err) {
   contest.save(function(err) {
      if (!err) {
          console.log("Added winners to contest")
      } else {
          console.log(err)
      }
   });
});
```